# Add repository from GitHub to Manage NuGet - Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, github, repository, nuget-package

I have an **ASP.NET project** and I would like to install a repository **from github**. 
I searched it with the 'Manage nuget' but I didn't found it. 
This is the respository that I want in my project: https://github.com/matthieua/WOW

What should do I to add a repository in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Team explorer-> Connect->Clone->Enter the url https://github.com/matthieua/WOW.git ->git clone

Comment: Thanks, but that it isn't install the respository in my project, only download the code from there.